# Even exponents making $\ 270270270\cdots 270270271\ $ prime

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Enzo Creti searched primes of the form $$270270270\cdots 270270271$$

The general expression for those numbers is $$\frac{270\cdot (1000^{n}-1)}{999}+1$$ when $\ "270"\ $ appears $\ n-1\ $ times. The even exponents $\ n>2\ $ giving a prime we found yet are $\ 12,740,788,7964\ $

Those even exponents have the following properties :

- They are divisible by $\ 4\ $ , but not by $\ 8\ $
- If we subtract $\ 1\ $ , we get a prime number. (even an emirp, that is a prime that is also prime when the digits in base $\ 10\ $ are written down in reverse order)

Moreover, the odd exponents that are multiples of $\ 3\ $ ($\ 3,9,129\ $) have the form $\ 2^n + 1\ $

> Is this pure coincidence or can it be shown that only such even exponents (apart from $\ 2\ $) can make the expression prime ?

Comment: A link to Enzo Creti's post would be nice.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92796/peter-and-mathphile

Comment: Note:  $17$ divides $\dfrac{270(1000^n-1)}{999}+1$ when $n=16k+8$